# How to write a SELECT DISTINCT query with ScalikeJDBC?

Tags: sql, scala, querydsl, scalikejdbc

How to write a `SELECT DISTINCT field FROM ...` query with `ScalikeJDBC` query DSL?

Comment: try this http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/query-dsl.html

Comment: Huh, I somehow disregarded the `distinct count` example thinking it only works with `count`. Thanks!